# $C^2$ function on closed domain has finite solutions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $\Omega $ be a bounded open set of $R^n$ and $f\in C^2(\overline\Omega)$. Define $N_f=\{x|x\in\Omega,J_f(x)=0\}$, where $J_f$ is the Jacobian of $f$.

How can I show that

> For all $ p\notin f(N_f)$ with 
>   $\inf\limits_{x\in\partial\Omega}||f(x)-p||>0,$ the equation $f(x)=p $
>   has a finite number of solutions ?

Comment: What is $J_f(x)$? And what difficulties do you have with this problem?

Comment: $J_f$ is Jacobi of $f$, I have solved it .Thank you .

Comment: If you'd like to give the community a gift you can answer your own question :-)

Comment: @dafinguzman I miss some condition $\Omega $ is bounded open set of $R^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have an infinite number of solutions arranged in a sequence $\{x_n\}$. As $\Omega$ is bounded, there is a convergent subsequence $\{x_{n_i}\}$. Set $x_0=\lim\limits_{i\rightarrow\infty}x_{n_i}$. Then, $f(x_0)=p$ by continuity and $x_0\in\Omega$ , since $\inf\limits_{x\in\partial\Omega}||f(x)-p||>0$.

Because $p\notin f(N_f)$, $J_f(x_0)\ne0$, but this contradicts the inverse function theorem.